# Order data not showing in observer function

Tags: enterprise-1.14.2.2

I am trying to create a handler for the Order place event using which I need to send the order data to some other table. I have created a module with config.xml and observer.php file. The handler function is called when order is placed, but the $observer objects does not return any order data.

My Sm/Sx/etc/config.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sm_Sx>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Sm_Sx>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <Sx>
                <class>Sm_Sx_Helper</class>
            </Sx>
        </helpers>
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <Sm_Sx_Model_Observer>
                        <class>Sm_Sx_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>create_sx_order</method>
                    </Sm_Sx_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

My Sm/Sx/Model/Observer.php is:

```
class Sm_Sx_Model_Observer
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //Just constrcutor for fun :-)
    }

    public function create_sx_order(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {

        $data = $observer->getData('Order');

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data);
        echo "</pre>";      
        exit;

        return $this;
    }   
}
```

I have tried using:

```
$data = $observer->getOrder();
```

And

```
$data = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
```

But nothing works. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try output in Magento log `Mage::log('orderData');
Mage::log($data->debug());`  you will see output in log.. if you are using exit then you will see the output in console.

Comment: I tried the log option also, but there is nothing in the log for the order data. I am using the exit. When outputting static text only, it shows in console. But fetching the order it fails, or shows nothing.

Comment: if you are using this  try `$data = $observer->getData('order');`

Comment: I am using this: $data = $observer->getData('Order'); I am not sure if small and caps "O" in Order makes any difference!

Comment: some time it make a difference. I don't know what is problem in you situation but i always get the data with this code `$data = $observer->getOrder();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it is too late, but just to post the solution. It worked using the code below:

```
$order=$observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$magento_order_id = $order->getId();
```

And in my config.XML:

```
<events>
    <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
            <Sm_Sx_Model_Observer>
                <class>Sm_Sx_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>create_sx_order</method>
            </Sm_Sx_Model_Observer>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_place_after>
    <catalog_product_load_after>
        <observers>
            <Sm_Sx_Model_Observer>
                <class>Sm_Sx_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>update_product_availability</method>
            </Sm_Sx_Model_Observer>
        </observers>
    </catalog_product_load_after>
</events>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few reasons, the event does nor fires this

- Maybe you do not create this module configuration file **Sm_Sx.xml**
  at `app/etc/modules`
- You used event `sales_order_place_after` does not fire always as per
  as**,my thought** it is only fire when Order object
  (`Mage_Sales_Model_Order`) is called [***`$orderObject->place()`***](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php#L1113).

I don't think it is always called, So **suggest to use another event which is called during order place**

like

- checkout_submit_all_after

> ```
> <?php
> Class [ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Observer{
>
>   public function checkoutOrderDetails($observer){
>   $order=$observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
>
>       if($order->getId()){
>           $ProdustIds=array();
>           foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item)
>           {
>               $item->getProductId();
>           }        
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```

**config.xml code**

> ```
> <global>
>     <events>
>         <checkout_submit_all_after>
>             <observers>
>                 <order_data_at_place>
>                     <type>singleton</type>
>                     <class>[ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Observer</class>
>                     <method>checkoutOrderDetails</method>
>                 </order_data_at_place>
>             </observers>
>         </checkout_submit_all_after>
>     </events>
> </global>
> ```